# How to return rows from a related table in single query Zend Framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, knockout.js, zend-db

I have two tables, Restaurants and RestaurantHours, which I need to return in a single result set. For each restaurant in the Restaurants table, there are 7 records in the RestaurantHours table.

I'm trying to return the data back in the following format, to use in my Knockout ViewModel.

Desired format of result (note some fields are omitted)

```
array(
 'name' => 'restaurant name here',
 'description' => 'restaurant description here',
 'hours' => array(
               '1' => array('open' => 1, 'day' => 1, 'open_time' => '8:00', 'close_time' => 10:00),
               '2' => array('open' => 1, 'day' => 2, 'open_time' => '8:00', 'close_time' => 10:00),
               '3' => array('open' => 1, 'day' => 3, 'open_time' => '8:00', 'close_time' => 10:00),
               '4' => array('open' => 1, 'day' => 4, 'open_time' => '8:00', 'close_time' => 10:00),
               '5' => array('open' => 1, 'day' => 5, 'open_time' => '8:00', 'close_time' => 10:00),
               '6' => array('open' => 1, 'day' => 6, 'open_time' => '8:00', 'close_time' => 10:00),
               '7' => array('open' => 1, 'day' => 7, 'open_time' => '8:00', 'close_time' => 10:00),
           )
);
```

So far I have been able to get all of the restaurants using the select below, but I'm not sure how to return the restaurant hours in the format I want, so on the client-side, I would have a collection of restaurant objects, each having it's own collection of restaurant hours, for each day of the week. I know how to join the tables, just not sure how I get the result set like I want using Zend DB.

**Restaurants**

```
  $select = $this->restaurantRepository->select();
  $select->setIntegrityCheck(false)
          ->from('restaurants')
          ->join('food_types', 'restaurants.food_type = food_types.id', array('foodType' => 'name'))               
          ->order('restaurants.name ASC');
  $restaurants = $this->restaurantRepository->getAdapter()->fetchAll($select);  

  return Zend_Json::encode($restaurants);
```

**Restaurant Hours**

```
// fetch all of the restaurant hours for the specified restaurant
$select = $this->restaurantHoursRepository
               ->select()
               ->from('restaurant_hours', array('id', 'restaurant_id', 'open', 'day', 'open_time' => 'DATE_FORMAT(open_time, "%H:%i")', 'close_time' => 'DATE_FORMAT(close_time, "%H:%i")'))
               ->where('restaurant_id = ' . $restaurant_id);

 return Zend_Json::encode($this->restaurantHoursRepository->fetchAll($select));
```

Basically I need to join these two queries together. Right now I'm having to return all of the restaurants and then when a restaurant object is bound in the ViewModel, I fetch the restaurant hours, which means a lot of ajax calls. I would really like to get this back down to just the one call, which loads all of the restaurants.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
$select = $this->restaurantRepository->select();
$select->setIntegrityCheck(false)
      ->from('restaurants')
      ->join('food_types', 'restaurants.food_type = food_types.id', array('foodType' => 'name'))               
      ->join('restaurant_hours', 'restaurants.id = restaurant_hours.restaurant_id', array('id', 'restaurant_id', 'open', 'day', 'open_time' => 'DATE_FORMAT(open_time, "%H:%i")', 'close_time' => 'DATE_FORMAT(close_time, "%H:%i")'))
      ->order('restaurants.name ASC');
  $restaurantsAndHours = $this->restaurantRepository->getAdapter()->fetchAll($select);  

  return Zend_Json::encode($restaurantsAndHours);
```

Comment: Close ....it returns the restaurant 7 times, once for each row in the restaurant hours table. Need it to be one restaurant record, with 7 restaurant hour records associated with it.

Comment: That is how a join returns records, you have to group them with a loop